# Horizontal LinearLayout in Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

What is a good way to do a `horizontalLayout` in anko / kotlin ? `verticalLayout` works fine - could set orientation on it but it feels wrong. Not sure what I am missing there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use a `linearLayout()` function instead.

```
linearLayout {
    button("Some button")
    button("Another button")
}
```

Comment: yeah, it was a bit confusing at first :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `LinearLayout` is by default horizontal, but I tend to be extra specific and rather use a separate `horizontalLayout` function for that.

You can simply add the `horizontalLayout` function to your project:

```
  val HORIZONTAL_LAYOUT_FACTORY = { ctx: Context ->
    val view = _LinearLayout(ctx)
    view.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
    view
  }

  inline fun ViewManager.horizontalLayout(@StyleRes theme: Int = 0, init: _LinearLayout.() -> Unit): _LinearLayout {
      return ankoView(HORIZONTAL_LAYOUT_FACTORY, theme, init)
  }
```

I have opened a feature request at Anko: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/413